# Why does this lengthy Wordpress web page not fully render in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome, wordpress-theming

I've been developing a site using the Virtue Free theme with Wordpress and have had no issues until now.  For some reason, when I navigate to [this page](http://www.kevin-schenk.com/lumenation/linecard/indoor/highbays-lowbays/) in Google Chrome, sometimes it renders the full page while other times the page's content seems to be covered up with a blank white box.  Ironically, the boxes clear away when I highlight the content that is hidden underneath the boxes.  Note that this only happens in Google Chrome (latest Mac & Windows versions [version 35]).  See image below for example.

[image]

Some research completed thus far:

- I was reading on Google that loading too many JavaScript and images could cause the page to stop rendering.  This page has a lot of images and JS scripts, so it's a plausible reason.  After further research, I moved as many of my scripts right before the close of the `<body>` tag.  It didn't solve the issue at hand and caused more issues.
- I tried disabling JS on the page, and the page successfully loaded without the issue.  I'm inclined to believe that one of my JS files is causing the issue, but after a couple hours of investigation, I couldn't pinpoint the file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it works fine on mine. may be you're seeing a cached version. try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: I've tried running this in Incognito Mode, and the issue still occurs.  The interesting thing is that some times the page fully loads while other times it doesn't.  Not sure if it could be a Chrome rendering issue?  It doesn't seem to happen on other browsers.